# Unable to update joomla 3.6.0 to any higher - blank screen after press update

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm unable to update from 3.6.0 to higher version - I get blank screen when I press update button or when I manually upload the file and try to update from downloaded zip file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the installed 3rd party extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try before the update:

1. In Global Configuration, set Error Reporting to "Maximum".
2. Update all third party extensions to the latest versions.
3. Try setting the PHP version to 5.6 if it's not already on 5.6.